# connection string not working

Tags: asp.net

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ERP;integrated security=SSPI"))
{}
```

when i include this line in asp.net web application,it shows..(Unrecognised escape sequence as error) locating \S in the connection string...
help me to connect..
Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 for not posting your password `:)`

Comment: @Kobi: integrated security=SSPI means windows authentication and not username/password

Comment: @Alex - I take joy in the simple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the @ sign before the start of your string to ignore escape sequences.

```
new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ERP;integrated security=SSPI"))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the "\" in your string that C# is interpreting as an escape sequence (for example a carriage return).

You can either:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ERP;integrated security=SSPI")) {}
```

Note the @ symbol.

or, you could use a double backslash:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SARAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ERP;integrated security=SSPI")) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SARAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ERP;integrated security=SSPI")) {}
```

Or

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ERP;integrated security=SSPI")) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct but you shouldn't hardcode this string. Read it from resource or configuration file.